# Endnotes in XSL:FO using FOP

Tags: xsl-fo, apache-fop

I was wondering why there's no possibility to code endnotes in XSL:FO right out of the box. I've found some approaches to generate endnotes from fo:footnote (like http://www.sagehill.net/docbookxsl/Endnotes.html) but I'd like to hear if there are any news meanwhile regarding this topic.
Most sources which say that FO doesn't support endnotes are quite old (around '00) so there may be any news?

I'm currently using FOP but I would also use another processor if it supports endnotes. Is there any?

Regards,
Chris

Answer (score 0):

I think the main reason why there is no XSL-FO endnote construct is that an endnote can be considered a special type of `fo:footnote`. And I don't think it is likely that endnotes will be added to the specification any time soon. The W3C document [XSL Requirements Version 2.0](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslfo20-req) is a collection of suggested new requirements for a future XSL 2.0 specification. Endnotes are not mentioned in that document.

[XEP](http://www.renderx.com/tools/index.html) and [Antenna House](http://www.antennahouse.com/product.htm) are two leading commercial FO processors. Both products provide several extensions to the XSL specification, but none of them are related to endnotes. This can be taken as another indication that the feature isn't much in demand.

The [XSL 2.0 Working Draft](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslfo20/) from September 2011 does not mention endnotes either.